# When I (facebook) like our video on our site, it turns into a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

as the subject describes, when I facebook-like an video-item or other type of page of our homepage, it turns into a whole "facebook page" instead of a timeline-post.

Why is that?

I have tried to lint it at the facebook-linter, and it says that there's noting wrong. The type of the video is "video.other".

E.g: http://metopia.se/tube/NKQeT/lanterna-education-summer-courses
When I liked that page, it turned into this page: 
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Lanterna-Education-Summer-Courses/334204833309981

Which I am admin for.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong; this is expected behavior:

1. Website owner puts FB Like button on site.
2. Website visitor clicks said Like button.
3. Timeline story is generated for the website visitor. It appears on his timeline and in his friends' News Feeds.

I liked the page myself to confirm.

What you're seeing is expected if you have liked the page and have also designated yourself as an admin for the page (i.e., whoever is denoted via the fb:admins Open Graph meta tag). Judging by that page's source I'm guessing you're either Adam or Mathias?

You should read up on Facebook's Open Graph protocol. In short, putting a Like button on a website will create a corresponding Open Graph fan page for whatever location is referenced by that Like button's href attribute.